Keras multiple inputs not working when passing a dictionary in model.fit
I am working on a model with multiple inputs and outputs. Passing the outputs as dictionary in model.fit works fine, but if I want to do the same with the inputs, I always get the following error:
Invalid input shape for input Tensor("data_1:0", shape=(None, 48, 2), dtype=float32). Expected shape (None, 1), but input has incompatible shape (None, 48, 2)

Arguments received by Functional.call():
  • inputs={'Linear_inputs': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)', 'LSTM_inputs': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 48, 2), dtype=float32)'}
  • training=True
  • mask={'Linear_inputs': 'None', 'LSTM_inputs': 'None'}

Process finished with exit code 1

My code for construction and training:
#input layers
Linear_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='Linear_inputs')
LSTM_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(step_size, 2), name='LSTM_inputs')

#common path
#x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(inputs)
#x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
#x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(inputs)
#x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)

#branch rotor speed
rpm = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer='l1l2', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(Linear_inputs)
Y_rpm = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='Y_rpm', kernel_regularizer='l1l2', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(rpm)

#branch active power
kW = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(40, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer='l2', kernel_initializer='RandomNormal')(LSTM_inputs)
kW = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(kW)
kW = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='tanh')(kW)
kW = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(kW)
Y_kW = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='Y_1_C')(kW)

#branch front bearing temp
f_C = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(40, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer='l2', kernel_initializer='RandomNormal')(LSTM_inputs)
f_C = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(f_C)
f_C = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='tanh')(f_C)
f_C = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(f_C)
Y_f_C = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='Y_2_C')(f_C)

#branch rear bearing temp
r_C = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(40, activation='tanh', kernel_regularizer='l2', kernel_initializer='RandomNormal')(LSTM_inputs)
r_C = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(r_C)
r_C = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='tanh')(r_C)
r_C = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(r_C)
Y_r_C = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='Y_O_C')(r_C)

#create model and optimizer
gearing_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[Linear_inputs, LSTM_inputs], outputs=[Y_rpm, Y_kW, Y_f_C, Y_r_C])

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
#optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.00001)

#define losses
losses = {"Y_rpm": "mse", "Y_1_C": "mse", "Y_2_C": "mse", "Y_O_C": "mse"}
lossWeights = {"Y_rpm": 1.0, "Y_1_C": 1.0, "Y_2_C": 1.0, "Y_O_C": 1.0}

#compile model
gearing_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=losses, loss_weights=lossWeights, metrics=["mse", "mse", "mse", "mse"])

reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.5, patience=3)

print(gearing_model.summary())

print(X_train_1_lin.shape)
print(X_train_1_lstm.shape)

history0 = gearing_model.fit({"Linear_inputs": X_train_1_lin, "LSTM_inputs": X_train_1_lstm},
                    {"Y_rpm": Y_train_1_lin, "Y_1_C": Y_train_1_lstm[:, 0], "Y_2_C": Y_train_1_lstm[:, 1], "Y_O_C": Y_train_1_lstm[:, 2]},
                    epochs=30, batch_size=128, callbacks=reduce_lr, shuffle=False)


history1 = gearing_model.fit([X_train_2_lin, X_train_2_lstm],
                    {"Y_rpm": Y_train_2_lin, "Y_1_C": Y_train_2_lstm[:, 0], "Y_2_C": Y_train_2_lstm[:, 1], "Y_O_C": Y_train_2_lstm[:, 2]},
                    epochs=30, batch_size=128, callbacks=reduce_lr, shuffle=False)

history2 = gearing_model.fit([X_train_3_lin, X_train_3_lstm],
                    {"Y_rpm": Y_train_3_lin, "Y_1_C": Y_train_3_lstm[:, 0], "Y_2_C": Y_train_3_lstm[:, 1], "Y_O_C": Y_train_3_lstm[:, 2]},
                    epochs=30, batch_size=128, callbacks=reduce_lr, shuffle=False)

I am using Python 3.12 and Keras 3.4.0.
Passing the inputs like it is done in history1 and history2 works, but the dictionary in history0 does not work. I have no problem with the outputs.
If I exchange X_train_1_lin with X_train_1_lstm it works - but I can't find a cause for this. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Please provide a minimal working example so that readers can test and see for themselves.

Try defining your model inputs as a dict:
tf.keras.Model(inputs={"Linear_inputs":Linear_inputs, "LSTM_inputs":LSTM_inputs], outputs=[Y_rpm, Y_kW, Y_f_C, Y_r_C])

Refrence:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/20136
